# How to set parent entity in child entity object without constructor and setter method in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities VacationTour and vacationTourDestinations. One tour can have multiple destinations. I want to save tour and destinations in the db using save() method of crudRepository with single save call. I don't want to manually set tour in the destination object. But I need the id of tour in destination as foreign key. Is this feasible?

VacationTourDestination.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vacationTourDestinations")
public class VacationTourDestination {
@Id
@Column(name = "Id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
protected int id;

@JoinColumn(name = "TourId")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
VacationTour tour;

@JoinColumn(name = "Country")
@ManyToOne
private Country country;

@Column(name = "destination")
String destination;
}
```

VacationTour.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vacationTours")
public class VacationTour {

@Id
@Column(name = "Id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
protected int id;

@Column(name = "adult")
int adult;
@Column(name = "child")
int child;
@Column(name = "infant")
int infant;

@Column(name = "termsAndConditions")
String TAC;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tour",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
protected List<VacationTourDestination> tourDestinations; 
}
```

Comment: Hibernate needs the getter/setter to work oterwise you get an exception. AFAIK there is no way around it

Comment: But because of this, I will have to call the save() method twice. First, when I have to save the vacationTour in DB which will return the same object with ID. Second, By setting this ID in vacationTourDestination object, I will have to call the save() method again.

Comment: on the margin: make some reading about List<> and Set<> in JPA entities. I Set is coherent with design ideas, has better performacne

Comment: @Nirav I believe you can set the parent before actually saving and then save both at the same time. If that doesn't work you need to call save() 2 times